# How Could I Make My Rect Follow My Guns Tip When My Gun Rotates? Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

[VIDEO](https://hastebin.com/ubuqevolev.m) I been having this problem quite a while I am trying to make my rect follow my guns tip so I could make my bullets look like they are coming out of my guns  tip but I am not really sure how I could do that I can only make my gun rotate and not make my bullets look like they are coming out of my guns tip [VIDEO](https://hastebin.com/ubuqevolev.m) as  you can see I have blitted the gun image and a small rect how would I make that rect rotate with my guns tip? what ever position the gun is at

here is the code you could run it with this image[image]

code

```
import pygame,random,math

pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("um..")



# how the gun is blitted



def blitRotate(surf, image, pos, originPos, angle):
 
    # calcaulate the axis aligned bounding box of the rotated image
    w, h = image.get_size()
    sin_a, cos_a = math.sin(math.radians(angle)), math.cos(math.radians(angle)) 
    min_x, min_y = min([0, sin_a*h, cos_a*w, sin_a*h + cos_a*w]), max([0, sin_a*w, -cos_a*h, sin_a*w - cos_a*h])
 
        # calculate the translation of the pivot 
    pivot        = pygame.math.Vector2(originPos[0], -originPos[1])
    pivot_rotate = pivot.rotate(angle)
    pivot_move   = pivot_rotate - pivot
 
        # calculate the upper left origin of the rotated image
    origin = (pos[0] - originPos[0] + min_x - pivot_move[0], pos[1] - originPos[1] - min_y + pivot_move[1])
 
        # get a rotated image
    rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(image, angle)

 
        # rotate and blit the image
    surf.blit(rotated_image, origin)

    

# the gun
class handgun():
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
 
        # LOL THESE IS THE HAND
        self.shootsright = pygame.image.load("hands.png")
        self.image = self.shootsright
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect(center = (self.x, self.y))
        self.look_at_pos = (self.x, self.y)
 
        self.isLookingAtPlayer = False
        self.look_at_pos = (x,y)
        self.hitbox = (self.x + -18, self.y, 46,60)

        self.gunDirection = "right"

    def draw(self,drawX,drawY):
        self.rect.topleft =  (drawX,drawY)
 
        # the guns hitbox
        # rotatiing the gun
        dx = self.look_at_pos[0] - self.rect.centerx
        dy = self.look_at_pos[1] - self.rect.centery 
            
        angle = (190/math.pi) * math.atan2(-dy, dx)
        gun_size = self.image.get_size()
        pivot = (8, gun_size[1]//2)
 
        blitRotate(window, self.image, self.rect.center, pivot, angle)

        if((angle > 90 or angle < -90) and self.gunDirection != "left"):
            self.gunDirection = "left"
            self.image = pygame.transform.flip(self.image, False, True)
        if((angle < 90 and angle > -90) and self.gunDirection != "right"):
            self.gunDirection = "right"
            self.image = pygame.transform.flip(self.image, False, True)

    def lookAt( self, coordinate ):
        self.look_at_pos = coordinate
 
 

 
white = (255,255,255)
handgun1 = handgun(300,300,10,10,white)




# the square that will be rotating with the gun



class portal:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
        self.direction = "blobright"

        self.angle = 0

    def draw(self,dx,dy):
        self.rect.topleft = (dx,dy)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)

        



white = (0,0,0)

port1 = portal(200,200,10,10,white)





# the main loop
runninggame = True
while runninggame:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            runninggame = False


    # fill the window black
    window.fill((255,255,255))

    # draw the rect that will be rotating with the gun tips

    port1.draw(handgun1.x,handgun1.y)

    # draw the gun
    handgun1.draw(port1.x,port1.y)

    handgun1.direction = "right"

    # gun rotation
    mousex, mousey = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if not handgun1.isLookingAtPlayer:
        handgun1.lookAt((mousex, mousey))



    pygame.display.update()
pygmae.quit()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not clear on your requirement, but I updated the code so the rectangle will always be in the firing line of the gun and always 100 pixels away.

To update the code:

-- In the handgun class change all `angle` references to `self.angle` so the angle can be accessed outside the class.

-- In the portal class (draw method), use the gun angle to position the rectangle:

```
def draw(self,dx,dy):
    # keep same distance from gun, use gun angle
    self.dist = 100
    dx = handgun1.x + self.dist*math.cos(-handgun1.angle*(math.pi/180)) -65 # why offset needed ?
    dy = handgun1.y + self.dist*math.sin(-handgun1.angle*(math.pi/180)) -50 # why offset needed ?
    self.rect.topleft = (dx,dy)
    pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)
```

For the circle to align with the gun origin, I had to offset the rectangle origin (-65, -50). I don't know why this is required.

[image]

Comment: thanks I think that would work I need it for shooting so the bullets look like they are coming out off the gun mouth

Comment: I am getting an error   'handgun' object has no attribute 'angle'

Comment: Change all `angle` to `self.angle` in the handgun class